# How can I sync podcasts (with progress) to my Android device with iTunes?

Tags: sync, podcast, itunes

I am a user of OS X, and would like to sync my Android device with iTunes.

I still use an iPhone and have a bunch of existing podcasts, and sometimes I use desktop to listen to podcasts, so two-way synchronization of files as well as progress would be quite useful. By progress I refer to time as well as whether an episode was completed. There is no need to sync with iOS devices directly; syncing with desktop iTunes on OS X is perfectly fine.

Any app that I found so far that even has sync apparently can sync only with itself on Android and iOS, but not with iTunes; or else it can import audio files from iTunes, ignoring progress.

Comment: Apple doesn't offer an API for other software to get information from iTunes, so unless Apple offers the app you're after, it's unlikely that anyone else has been able to make one.

Comment: Dobar dan, you could use sticher to organize your podcasts. It'll sync folders/progress from the web and the app as long as you log in.

Comment: @DanHulme, there is software out there that directly interfaces with iTunes's database. Among others, Google Music Manager parses the playlists for uploading a subset.

Answer (score 0):

[DoubleTwist](http://www.doubletwist.com/) was built for a similar purpose and does the job well. To use it, you can simply [install the Mac app](http://www.doubletwist.com/desktop/) and the [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer) and use their [DoubleTwist Sync](http://www.doubletwist.com/announcement/) feature to synchronize iTunes with Android.

Comment: It seems to get quite close, except it doesn't do reverse-sync on Mac. Also, can you clarify: does it sync podcast progress, which is my main requirement?